# Delegate method not being called by viewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, delegates, protocols

So here's what's going on (other than me being a noob).

I have two view controllers, AddAPlaceViewController and showCategoriesViewController.

I have a table cell in AddAPlaceVC which you tap and showCategoriesVC (which is a tableviewcontroller) opens up (modal) and gives you a list of ten options. You tap one of them or tap on the cancel button.

I've spent days understanding and figuring out protocols and delegates. I think I have them set up right but can't figure out why they aren't working or getting called. I've tried all sorts of changes but no luck so far.

You guys are my only hope! :)

Here's the important bits of the code:

AddAPlaceViewController.h

```
AddAPlaceViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "showCategoriesViewController.h"


@interface AddAPlaceViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ShowCategoriesViewControllerDelegate>
```

AddAPlaceViewController.m

```
AddAPlaceViewController.m

#import "AddAPlaceViewController.h"
#import "FSQVenue.h"
#import "Categories.h"
//#import "showCategoriesViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Un-highlight the selected cell

    [categoryTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    showCategoriesViewController *SCVC = [[showCategoriesViewController alloc] init];



    SCVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showCategories"];

    SCVC.categoryDelegate = self;

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:SCVC animated:YES];


}

#pragma mark showCategoriesViewControllerDelegate

-(void)didSelectOptions:(NSInteger )selectedCategory
{
    NSInteger category = selectedCategory;

    NSLog(@"Add Places %d", category);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)didCancelOptions
{
    NSLog(@"Add Places -- Dismiss Button Pressed");

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

showCategoriesViewController.h

```
showCategoriesViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ShowCategoriesViewControllerDelegate;


@interface showCategoriesViewController : UITableViewController
{
     id<ShowCategoriesViewControllerDelegate>categoryDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ShowCategoriesViewControllerDelegate> categoryDelegate;

- (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender;

@end

@protocol ShowCategoriesViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didSelectOptions:(NSInteger )selectedCategory;
- (void)didCancelOptions;


@end
```

showCategoriesViewController.m

```
showCategoriesViewController.m

#import "showCategoriesViewController.h"
#import "Categories.h"


@interface showCategoriesViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *categoryArray;

@end

@implementation showCategoriesViewController

@synthesize categoryDelegate = _categoryDelegate;

@synthesize categoryArray;


…

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [_categoryDelegate didSelectOptions:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Selected IndeXPath %@", cell);
    NSLog(@"Selected IndeXPath GOING TO DELEGATE %d", indexPath.row);


}


- (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender {

    [_categoryDelegate didCancelOptions];
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely guess? In the code you posted, both your property and your ivar are called `categoryDelegate`, yet you treat your property as though it refers to an ivar called `_categoryDelegate`. Probably this is just a typo, but because iOS allows calls to methods on null objects (and just doesn't do anything), it fails silently. Renaming the ivar to `_categoryDelegate` should fix it.

Comment: I checked the debug console and you're right. It is calling the method on null objects. _categoryDelegate objc_object * 0x00000000. How can I fix that? Sorry, I'm kinda new at this.

Comment: Change this line `id<ShowCategoriesViewControllerDelegate>categoryDelegate;` inside the `@interface showCategoriesViewController` declaration to `id<ShowCategoriesViewControllerDelegate> _categoryDelegate;`

Comment: @Amit Wadhawan, Unless you're using an old version of Xcode, you don't need to declare the ivar at all, or use '@synthesize'. Just declare the property, and the ivar (with the name _categoryDelegate) is created automatically.

Comment: I just tried id<ShowCategoriesViewControllerDelegate> _categoryDelegate; and also tried removing the @synthesize but it's still not working.

Comment: As far as I know (using Xcode 4.3 for my part), the `@synthesize` keyword is still required for it to create an ivar automatically. The rest is accurate though. Regarding the code not working, did you try with the rename but leaving the @synthesize in?

Comment: Yeah. It gives me a warning when I remove the @synthesize statement (Xcode 4.5). I can't figure out what it could be... So frustrating!

Comment: With the rename in place and the @synthesize *still included as is*, is _categoryDelegate still nil when you call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Yup. It's still nil. Also, I had to add a '__weak' in front of id<ShowCategoriesViewControllerDelegate> _categoryDelegate; otherwise it was giving me an error.

Comment: Your property isn't getting set properly, but I can't see why: from the code provided, it should work. Does showCategoriesViewController include a method called `setCategoryDelegate`? If so, rename/delete it - it may interfere with the property.

Comment: Nope. Just checked. I'm following the same format everywhere.

Comment: Is either categoryDelegate or _categoryDelegate being accessed/set *anywhere* else in showCategoriesViewController? One check to run is to add the following method: `- (void) setCategoryDelegate:(id)del { NSLog(@"Set categoryDelegate to: %@", del); _categoryDelegate = del; }`. This will log any attempt to change the `categoryDelegate` property and what it's being set to, which may offer some clues.

Comment: @Xono The response from the method-> Set categoryDelegate to: <AddAPlaceViewController: 0x72d53c0>

Comment: And that's the only log that comes out? Means the property is being set, just not getting through to the ivar. Next: change this line `[_categoryDelegate didSelectOptions:indexPath.row];` in showCategoriesViewController to use the property rather than directly pulling the ivar - change it to: `[self.categoryDelegate didSelectOptions:indexPath.row];`

Comment: So changed the ivar to self.categoryDelegate. Here's the new Logs --> Set categoryDelegate to: <AddAPlaceViewController: 0x72e9ab0>
2012-10-10 22:20:17.138 LiveMyJourney[21428:11903] Selected IndeXPath <UITableViewCell: 0x75c2b80; frame = (0 352; 320 44); text = 'Sights'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x75c2c80>>
2012-10-10 22:20:17.138 LiveMyJourney[21428:11903] Selected IndeXPath GOING TO DELEGATE 8
2012-10-10 22:20:40.340 LiveMyJourney[21428:11903] Button Pressed

Comment: The delegate method is AddAPlace still isn't being called though.

Comment: @Xono Figured it out!!! I had a storyboard segue set between the view controllers that was preventing the delegate to be set. Added it in the prepareForSegue method and it's all good now. Thanks for all the help you gave :)

Comment: O.o so you were attempting transitioning using alloc/init, presentModalViewController, *and* a segue? Very confusing, generally you should stick to one (if storyboards are available, segue is usually preferred). Sorry I couldn't be more help, but your code didn't indicate anywhere the use of a segue. Glad you figured it out though :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have presentModalViewController: your **SCVC**, your **AddAPlaceViewController** is inactive. Its better if you can create your showCategoriesViewController as a subclass of UITableView with your custom delegate method.

Reference [Link](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/09/creating-delegate-for-custom-class.html)

Comment: @required is the default, so he shouldn't need to include that.

Comment: You're right @rdelmar. Neo, Already tried that with no success :(

Comment: @NEo Any ideas on how to do that? :)

Comment: Create a custom class as a subclass of UIView. There add your TableView and your custom delegate methods. And in your AddAPlaceViewController, instead of presentModalViewController: use addSubview: method..... you can see the link above as a reference

Comment: The basic idea would be to have a second tableView on AddAPlace, which is added to the ViewController/made visible instead of presenting showCategories, and setting it's delegate to AddAPlace (you could use the tableView.tag to differentiate between the two tables). I doubt this is the issue though - the fact the AddAPlace ViewController is in the background shouldn't stop it receiving calls.

Comment: Yup. I want to be able to use showCategories in other places as well so I would rather have it as a separate view controller. I feel as if it should work. It's the simplest use of delegates and protocols (IMO).